# Hebrew Text Is Rendered As Random Symbols

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I’m setting up a new server that will serve content in Hebrew. I'd like to support UTF-8 fully in my web application. Where do I need to set the encoding/charsets?”

The returned data is coming from DB which is set to utf8, been able to console.log the data on windows and get correct Hebrew content.

im using the core http module
problem is when preforming the following

```
let data = JSON.stringify(data);
res.write(data);
```

by default http.res.write uses ut8 encoding.

Sample of Hebrew content poorly decoded:

```
projectStatus":"×‘×—×™×¨×ª ×“×™×¨×•×ª"
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The encoding needs to be set in the header with a meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```